# Multiple text to columns in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry I'm attempting VBA for the first time and am not too sure how to perform a text to column of multiple columns.

I have set up my values in columns AN, AO and AP.

I would like to:
1) text to column AN into AQ - AZ

2) text to column AO into column BA - BE

3) text to column AP into column BF - BJ

I have started my code this way, but whatever range i'm trying shows me an error:

```
Dim count As Integer

count = Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("A1", 
Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count - 1

For i = 1 To count
```

???? what happens next?

I have empty cells in these columns that i wish to perform text to columns, hence am referencing column A which is a completely filled list of my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick sample:

---

**<sub>Sample Data:</sub>**

[image]

Or in your specific case:

[image]

---

**<sub>Sample Code:</sub>**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()

Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range, Area as Range

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range(Replace("B2:B?,F2:F?,J2:J?", "?", lr))
    For Each Area In rng.Areas
        Area.TextToColumns Destination:=Area.Offset(0, 1).Resize(Area.Rows.Count, 3), DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True
    Next Area
End With

End Sub
```

Another, possibily easier to understand method, could be:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = .Range(Replace("B2:B?,F2:F?,J2:J?", "?", lr))
    Set rng2 = .Range(Replace("C2:E?,G2:I?,K2:M?", "?", lr))
    For x = 1 To rng1.Areas.Count
        rng1.Areas(x).TextToColumns Destination:=rng2.Areas(x), DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

Or in your specific case:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = .Range(Replace("AN2:AN?,AO2:AO?,AP2:AP?", "?", lr))
    Set rng2 = .Range(Replace("AQ2:AZ?,BA2:BE?,BF2:BJ?", "?", lr))
    For x = 1 To rng1.Areas.Count
        rng1.Areas(x).TextToColumns Destination:=rng2.Areas(x), DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

---

**<sub>Sample Result:</sub>**

[image]

Or in your specific case:

[image]

---

<sub>**Note1:** Just change the range references to suit your needs</sub>

<sub>**Note2:** Since you haven't provided what type of data, nor which delimiter you have used; you might need to play around with the [text-to-columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns) parameters</sub>

Comment: Any luck with this @jade.elves

Comment: thank you so much JvdV! it worked seamlessly for what I needed to do

Comment: @jade.elves glad to hear. In that case, please accept as answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer and also consider to upvote if this has been helpfull.